How to keep my flutter countdown notification running even when app is removed from recent apps?
I have been trying to run a countdown in my notification panel with my app. But every time i remove the app from recent apps the timer pauses at the last time before closing the app completely.

i have tried a few things you can see below

main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:ly/screens/countdown_page.dart';
import 'package:ly/services/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() {
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  notificationService.flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon'),
    ),
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) async {
      if (response.payload != null && response.payload == 'cake_button') {
        // Navigate to a specific screen
        // Add your navigation logic here
      }
    },
  );
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Lawfully Yours',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const CountdownPage(),
    );
  }
}

countdown_page.dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:ly/services/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:ly/utils/colors.dart';

class CountdownPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountdownPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CountdownPage> createState() => _CountdownPageState();
}

class _CountdownPageState extends State<CountdownPage> {
  late Timer _countdownTimer;
  String remainingHours = '00';
  String remainingMinutes = '00';
  String remainingSeconds = '00';
  final NotificationService _notificationService = NotificationService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Start the countdown timer
    _startCountdown();
    // Schedule the birthday notification
    _notificationService.scheduleBirthdayNotification(DateTime(2024, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0));
    // Show the silent countdown notification
    _notificationService.showSilentCountdownNotification(DateTime(2024, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _countdownTimer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _startCountdown() {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final userBirthday = DateTime(2024, 6, 15, 0, 0, 0); // June 15, 2024, 12:00 AM

    // Calculate remaining time until user's birthday
    final difference = userBirthday.difference(now);

    setState(() {
      final totalHours = difference.inHours;
      remainingHours = '$totalHours';
      remainingMinutes = '${difference.inMinutes.remainder(60)}';
      remainingSeconds = '${difference.inSeconds.remainder(60)}';
    });

    // Update countdown every second
    _countdownTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      final now = DateTime.now();
      final difference = userBirthday.difference(now);

      if (difference.isNegative) {
        _countdownTimer.cancel();
        _notificationService.showBirthdayNotification();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          final totalHours = difference.inHours;
          remainingHours = '$totalHours';
          remainingMinutes = '${difference.inMinutes.remainder(60)}';
          remainingSeconds = '${difference.inSeconds.remainder(60)}';
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/cd_bg.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      colors: [
                        AppColors.primary,
                        Color(0xFF865368),
                      ],
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(33.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(33.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 40,
                            height: 10,
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                color: AppColors.accent,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'COUNTDOWN',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.text,
                              fontFamily:
                                  GoogleFonts.dmSerifDisplay().fontFamily,
                              fontSize: 40,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              _buildCountdownBox(remainingHours),
                              _buildCountdownBox(remainingMinutes),
                              _buildCountdownBox(remainingSeconds),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCountdownBox(String value) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.text,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          value.padLeft(2, '0'),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.dmSerifDisplay().fontFamily,
            fontSize: 40,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

notification_service.dart i am talking about the showSilentCountdownNotification in this file.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  NotificationService() {
    _initializeNotifications();
  }

  void _initializeNotifications() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/launcher_icon');
    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
    );
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
  }

  Future<void> showBirthdayNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'birthday_channel',
      'Birthday Notifications',
      channelDescription: 'Channel for birthday notifications',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      color: Color(0xFF6A1B9A),
      playSound: true,
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
        'Let’s cut your cake and celebrate this special day together!',
        contentTitle: 'Happy Birthday, My Love!',
        summaryText: 'Tap to celebrate!',
        htmlFormatContent: true,
        htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
        htmlFormatSummaryText: true,
      ),
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      'Happy Birthday, My Love!',
      'Let’s cut your cake and celebrate this special day together!',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'birthday_notification',
    );
  }

  Future<void> scheduleBirthdayNotification(DateTime scheduledDate) async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'birthday_channel',
      'Birthday Notifications',
      channelDescription: 'Channel for birthday notifications',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      color: Color(0xFF6A1B9A),
      playSound: true,
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
        'Let’s cut your cake and celebrate this special day together!',
        contentTitle: 'Happy Birthday, My Love!',
        summaryText: 'Tap to celebrate!',
        htmlFormatContent: true,
        htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
        htmlFormatSummaryText: true,
      ),
    );
    const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      1,
      'Happy Birthday, My Love!',
      'Let’s cut your cake and celebrate this special day together!',
      tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduledDate, tz.local),
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.wallClockTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    );
  }

  Future<void> showSilentCountdownNotification(DateTime userBirthday) async {
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'countdown_channel',
      'Countdown Notifications',
      channelDescription: 'Channel for countdown notifications',
      importance: Importance.low,
      priority: Priority.low,
      playSound: false,
      vibrationPattern: Int64List(0),
      ongoing: true,
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
        'Time remaining: ${_formatDuration(userBirthday.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds)}',
        contentTitle: 'Birthday Countdown',
        summaryText: 'Time remaining: ${_formatDuration(userBirthday.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds)}',
        htmlFormatContent: true,
        htmlFormatContentTitle: true,
        htmlFormatSummaryText: true,
      ),
    );
    final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      2,
      'Birthday Countdown',
      'Time remaining: ${_formatDuration(userBirthday.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds)}',
      platformChannelSpecifics,
    );

    // Update countdown every second
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      final seconds = userBirthday.difference(DateTime.now()).inSeconds;

      if (seconds <= 0) {
        timer.cancel();
        cancelSilentCountdownNotification();
      } else {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          2,
          'Birthday Countdown',
          'Time remaining: ${_formatDuration(seconds)}',
          platformChannelSpecifics,
        );
      }
    });
  }

  void cancelSilentCountdownNotification() {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(2);
  }

  String _formatDuration(int seconds) {
    final Duration duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
    return '${duration.inHours}:${(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }
}

Please someone provide me a perfect example on how to keep the notification system running even when app closed.

for reference I have been using flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2. I have tried using flutter_foreground_services and flutter_background_services as well, but nothing worked for me accurately.


Also I want to know whether it is because i am using in run without debuging mode thats why it is not working. is it so??

please someone help quickly!! provide a working modern solution. thanks
